# How can I set up an OPEN VPN client-server communication between two linux machines?

Tags: openvpn

I have two linux machines having Openvpn-2.1.1 installed. I want to configure a client-server communication between the above linux machines How can i do that?

I just want a basic method na procedure thats all.

/renjithg

Answer (score 1):

In OpenVPN's own documentation you have a couple of examples, including the [Static Key Mini-HOWTO](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html) which is among the most minimal configurations you can achieve. It won't get more basic than that.

Comment: ok i'll try that one.